# escape the 'escape' value of the Last escape slash in a file

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk, delimiter

I have a datafile that is delimited by \001 or ^A character. So the data looks like this

```
1234^A This is Ma Baker ^A Gimme all your money ^A \0000123\^A
```

I would like to search for the ^A pattern which is actually like \001 in ASCII 
   I could use something like   this. I can manage the below e.g.

```
 sed e/string / substitute 
    \M\a\B\a\k\e\r\s\h\g\a\v\e   |  sed -e 's_\\_\\\\_g'
```

But I dont know how to search for the ^A character (I cant see it normally with Cat or view ) and I need to find just those backslashes that precede the ^A. So whats happening here is that - there is a false message sent , to the command that processes the file to ignore ^A as delimiter ( when the delimiter is preceded by the backslash )  when in fact it has to be respected . So I need to double escape the backslash like above to  remove the "escape"  property of it and treat it like a literal

Comment: So you want to find the last octal 1 `\001` in a file and replace it with what exactly?

Comment: You can't just assume something is escaped. Its more complicated than that. 'thi\\s' is not escape s. Its an escape plus an s. 'Thi\\\\\\s' isin't either. 'Thi\\\\\s' is however. `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(\\(?!\\).)` is a correct regex to find escaped anything.

Comment: Thx.say I have this file `Sam^ATom^AMary\^AJane^A` the delimiter is ^A. So the file splits as `Sam Tom  Mary Jane` . Well supposed to but there is a \^A before Jane. That \ is actually part of the data but it that sequence escapes the ^A . So now the same file is split as `Sam Tom MaryJane` .Delimiter between Mary and Jane is ignored. I want to catch such situations and escape the \^A  with \\^A.So after this the file will look like `Sam Tom Mary\ Jane`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this sed to match escaped `^A` and double escape it:

```
sed 's~\\\x01~\\&~g'
```